# Radio buttons cancel eachother out and it can check multiple and it needs to be only one

Tags: php, sql, radio-button

I have different questions but the radio buttons go out if i press a different one with the same value. I can check multiple and i want it to be only one because it should be that you can only choose one

I tried giving them some different names but it didn't work

```
<?php
include '../include/db_conn.php';
$url = $_GET['surveyUrl'];
$sqlGetSurvey = 'SELECT * FROM `survey_info` WHERE `survey_url`="'. $url .'"';
$resultGetSurvey = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlGetSurvey);

if ($resultGetSurvey ->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $resultGetSurvey-> fetch_assoc()) {
        $surveyId = $row['survey_id'];
        $sqlGetQuestion = 'SELECT * FROM `survey_questions` WHERE `survey_id`="'. $surveyId .'"';
        $sqlGetSurvey = 'SELECT * FROM `survey_info` WHERE `survey_id`="'. $surveyId .'"';
        $resultGetQuestion = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlGetQuestion);
        $resultGetSurvey = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlGetSurvey);
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultGetSurvey)) {
            $text_color = $row['survey_text_color'];
            $background_color = $row['survey_background_color'];
            $theme_color = $row['survey_theme_color'];
        }
        if ($resultGetQuestion ->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $resultGetQuestion-> fetch_assoc()) {
                $questionId = $row['question_id'];
                $count = 'A';
                $i = 0;

                $yuyu = '<ul class="list-group mx-auto mt-3">
                <li class="list-group-item">'. $row['question'] .'</li>';

                $sqlGetAnswers = 'SELECT * FROM `survey_question_answers` WHERE `question_id`='. $questionId .'';
                $resultGetAnswers = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlGetAnswers);

                if ($resultGetAnswers ->num_rows > 0) {
                    while ($row = $resultGetAnswers-> fetch_assoc()) {
                        $yuyu .= "<li class='list-group-item'><span class='badge badge-light main-color-bg'>". $count .". <input type='radio' name='q[$i]' value'$count'></span> ". $row['answer'] ."</li>";

                        ++$count;
                        ++$i;
                    }
                }echo $yuyu;
                echo '</ul>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that I can check one at a time and that they dont cancel eachother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio inputs should have the same name to work together. Since your radio buttons should be "grouped" within a question, the name should contain the `$questionId` to make the name unique to each question:

Change

```
$yuyu .= "<li class='list-group-item'><span class='badge badge-light main-color-bg'>". $count .". <input type='radio' name='q[$i]' value'$count'></span> ". $row['answer'] ."</li>";
```

to

```
$yuyu .= "<li class='list-group-item'><span class='badge badge-light main-color-bg'>". $count .". <input type='radio' name='q_$questionId' value='$count'></span> ". $row['answer'] ."</li>";
```

I replaced the `name` attribute to include the `$questionId` and fixed the `value'$count'` part that was missing the `=`.